# Unnecessary assignment of variables

Tags: c#, variables, try-catch

I have question about unnecessary assignments of variables.

I have lot of functions and some of them when they catch exception they will write it into logfile.

For example this is one of them(Just rename PC using powershell):

```
public static bool SetMachineName(string name)
{
        try
        {
            Runspace rs;
            rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            rs.Open();

            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("Rename-computer");
                ps.AddParameter("newname", name);
                ps.Runspace = rs;
                ps.Invoke();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter loger = new LogWriter(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
}
```

And when im creating logwriter to write into file it says "Unnecessary assigments of a value to 'loger' but it does only in some function.

For example im not getting this error in this function:

```
public static bool VPNAdapterExists(string VPNAdapterName)
    {
        try
        {
            // VPN adapters are stored in the rasphone.pdk
            // "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
                          @"\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk";

            const string pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(path), pattern)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
                .ToArray();

            bool has = matches.Contains(VPNAdapterName);

            if (has == true) { return true; }
            else { return false; }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter loger = new LogWriter(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Its a class with just bunch of functions sometimes i get this warning sometimes i dont. And only in "Catch" block im not getting this in "Try" blocks.

I dont know if you need LogWriter class too so here it is:

```
public class LogWriter
{
    private string m_exePath = string.Empty;
    public LogWriter(string logMessage)
    {
        LogWrite(logMessage);
    }
    public void LogWrite(string logMessage)
    {
        if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
            using (FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

                bool LogginEnabled;

                LogginEnabled = info.EnableLogging;
                if (LogginEnabled == true)
                {
                    m_exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                    try
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt"))
                        {
                            Log(logMessage, w);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter txtWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            txtWriter.Write("\r\n");
            txtWriter.Write("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            txtWriter.Write("  : {0}", logMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what cause this problem and why is it so random?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: LogWriter loger = new LogWriter(ex.ToString()); like this  in every exception, maybe i had to write "Create" instead of call.

Comment: You *don't use* `logger` local variable; that's why `new LogWriter(ex.ToString());` is *enough*

Comment: Consider making your `LogWriter` class `static`. No need to create a new instance each time, it doesn't hold any state anyway.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh i see, but i still dont get why i dont get this warning in other functions then? i dont see difference between them

Comment: @TimSchmelter and if i use it as above like: `new LogWriter(ex.ToString());` how Dmitry Bychenko wrote? Would that work too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first.

The biggest problem here is that you log stuff in logger constructor. That is not what constructor should be doing. Constructor has to construct an object properly for later use. And that is all.

It should look like that:

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.WriteLog(ex.Message);
```

Constructor should NOT call LogWrite.

So the warning you are receiving means - "You assign Logger to logger variable, but then you don't do anything on that logger object. So why this assignment?"

You can also make it some kind of utility class:

```
static class Logger
{
    public static void WriteLog(string message)
    {
       //just write log here.
    }
}
```

Then you can use it just like that:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   Logger.WriteLog(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: Additionally: This is fine as exercise but a logging framework (log4net, NLog, Serilog...), which offers a lot of possibilities, should be used for a real world application